# Page loading problem. Page is very slow

Tags: php, server, page-speed

Regarding the domain http://www.pravninasvet.com, there is a problem where it sometimes loads fast, sometimes very slow.

The domain is registered by godaddy, the server is in Germany. But when the page loads very slow, the is ping normal:

```
Pinging pravninasvet.com [91.194.91.202] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 91.194.91.202: bytes=32 time=52ms TTL=55
Reply from 91.194.91.202: bytes=32 time=50ms TTL=55
Reply from 91.194.91.202: bytes=32 time=52ms TTL=55
Reply from 91.194.91.202: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=55

Ping statistics for 91.194.91.202:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 50ms, Maximum = 52ms, Average = 51ms
```

Can this be a problem with the server being in Germany and domain registered at godaddy? Or what else can be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can verify that you do indeed have performance issues.

Your server may very well be partly to blame, but you also have some significant on-page issues that you could also look to mitigate your slow-site problem:
http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.pravninasvet.com/Ilad9BMy (45 seconds to load)

Additionally, you could reduce the size (KB) of your website:
http://173-203-64-171.static.cloud-ips.com/scan-files/free/d23b5c8ee7d85829ab157ccc579cfde9/report.html

Lastly, you might want to check that your DNS problems aren't causing additional lookup delays:
http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=www.pravninasvet.com

Comment: thx will try it.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo!'s [Yslow addon for Firefox](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) and [Chrome](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2011/03/yslow-for-chrome/) will analyze a page and help point out factors affecting the loading speed of the site.

Google's [Page Speed tools](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) will also analyze pages to find what is slowing them down.

You may want to try installing one of these tools and running it on this site. They won't catch all of the possible problems, but will help you figure out how to optimize the code being sent to the browser so that it takes less time to load, and discover network issues that might be affecting performance.

Comment: thx will try it.

Comment: The link I gave (gtmetrix.com) does both YSlow and Google's Page Speed together, with a combined resource on how to address any issues.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware of that @MikeHudson. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your website and you have a lot of assets (javascript files and css files). This is unneccessary overkill.

I just finished a project where my team implemented http://code.google.com/p/minify/ into our CMS which dynamically adds assets for our visitors based on a lot of variables. The reason I mentioned that is because minify is extremely flexible.

The idea is that you want to combine all your javascript and css.

The next step is to serve them from a cookieless domain depending on how much you want to spend to enhance the customer experience. But I would just focus on combining the scripts and css files and then optimize the images.

Another tip is that you can create a subdomain such as images.MyDomain.com and serve the images from there.

Comment: Hi, asome. Will try your minify in my project to see if works.

Comment: what about ASPX? Do you have any version for aspx or just for php?

Comment: @senzacionale: Not sure about working with ASPX but I did find some responses on stackoverflow for minifying via asp and asp.net Check out the following responses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670563/whats-the-best-way-to-minify-the-asp-net-generated-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877016/javascript-minifier-e-g-yui-integrated-to-asp-net-webdeploy-publish http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898446/can-yui-compressor-minify-asp-net-inline-script

Answer (score 1):

I would bet on the problem being with your host. If you have more than one site on that server you can see if they are slow at the same time. If it's a shared server you can also try finding sites that share your ip using http://www.myipneighbors.com/ and see if they're slow when you are.

If that's the problem there's not much you can do other than upgrading your plan or finding a new host. That's assuming the slowdown is from other people's traffic. If the high traffic is coming from you then just moving won't help, you would definitely need a server with more resources.

Comment: thx will try it.