# How to diagnose slow loading web pages?

Tags: server, page-speed

Pages at my domain sometimes load very slow.

The domain is registered at 101domain, server is in Europe.

```
Reply from 91.185.209.164: bytes=32 time=60ms TTL=60
Reply from 91.185.209.164: bytes=32 time=58ms TTL=60
Reply from 91.185.209.164: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=60
Reply from 91.185.209.164: bytes=32 time=61ms TTL=60
```

Is this because the domain is registered on the other side of the world?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page loading problem. Page is very slow](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10960/page-loading-problem-page-is-very-slow)

Comment: tnx nick, i checked that other suggestion, but i dont think this is  it, on that site they seem to have a lot of javascript, not much here. think i should move domain to another server?

Comment: I removed your domain name to keep this from being too localized.

Comment: I checked this morning and the TTL was 49 from the uk - load time was very fast. Where are you hosted compared to where you live?

Answer (score 2):

You can test your websites loading at http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/ also you should run it through http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ I don't think your websites load time would affect your ping response though so I suspect its a routing issue that's out of your control. You can also run a traceroute to see which hop is lagging.

Comment: tnx, I contacted my hosting company , apperantly they got it fixed now. I see that I can speed up my pages on my own too. tnx anaglo for your link. :)

Comment: You're welcome if you feel it helped check it off as the answer :)